# Help with Regex to match and rewrite URI

Tags: regex, url, .htaccess

I need to have a RegEx that will match a URI like this based on the subdomain "blog"--

http://blog.foo.com/2010/06/25/city-tax-sale/

and redirect like this (getting rid of the subdomain and numbers/date)--

http://foo.com/city-tax-sale/

where the last bit "city-tax-sale" would be a wildcard.  So basically any incoming URI that starts with 'blog.foo.com' would be redirected to 'foo.com' + 'whatever is at the end of the above URI after the three sub paths with numbers.

I hope that makes sense.  Just trying to create one redirect instead of writing every single one.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This will explicitly match your date format, rather than any series of digits and slashes:

```
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^blog\.foo\.com$ [NC]
RewriteRule ^/\d{4}/\d{2}/\d{2}/(.*)$ http://foo.com/$1 [L,R=301]
```

The regex part can be broken does to:

```
^      # start of non-domain url
/\d{4} # slash followed by 4 digits
/\d{2} # slash followed by 2 digits
/\d{2} # slash followed by 2 digits
/      # closing slash
(.*)   # rest of the url, captured to group 1
$      # end of url
```

With the `$1` in the replacement being group 1.

In the options part:
`L` is for "Last" - tells it to not bother looking at other rules.
`R=301` is for Redirect with 301 header, which means permanent redirect (just R would send a temporary 302 header)

The RewriteCond bit performs a case-insensitive (NC option) check on the `HTTP_HOST` header (supplied by user/client) and if it starts `blog.foo.com` it performs the rewrite, otherwise it doesn't.

Comment: *"So basically **any incoming URI that starts with 'blog.foo.com'** would be redirected to 'foo.com"*

Comment: Ah, missed the //blog.foo.com -> //foo.com part.

Comment: Ok, fixed that now. Also since RewriteCond is a regex, I escaped the `.`s and added an ending marker - still works without, but meh.

Comment: it's still more specific than what the OP asked for. :)

Comment: Thanks, this is perfect and probably eliminated any follow up questions!  Cheers!

Answer (score 2):

```
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^blog.foo.com [NC] 
RewriteRule ^(\d+/)+(.*)/?$ http://foo.com/$2 [L,R=301]
```

Answer (score 0):

You can try this:

```
/http:\/\/blog\..*\.[a-zA-Z]{2,5}\/[0-9]{4}\/[0-9]{2}\/[0-9]{2}\/(.*)\//
```

Comment: this will rewrite not redirect.